# iPod nano synchronization

Tags: sync, ipod

I have just had my laptop repaired, and cannot find my last iPOD backup, I want to sync my Nano to my pc one way, if this is possible, how can i do it?

Babyt

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Windows, [sharepod](http://www.getsharepod.com/) might be helpful in copying over the music from your iPod. If you're on a Mac, give senuti a try.

Answer (score 0):

For windows, [Pod Player](http://www.ipodsoft.com/site/pmwiki.php?n=PodPlayer.HomePage) can extract you music from you iPod (and play it off the ipod etc').
It's one small file (0.5MB) that doesn't need installation.

I usually carry it on the iPod itself, so no matter what computer I'm at, I can always use it and get my music out. :)